# Simple ModalService for Angular 7 does not open: No component factory found for

Tags: angular, angular7

I am creating an Angular's 7 ModalService that simply opens a Modal ([StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service)).

The Modal content should be a Component passed to the Modal when opening.

**Modal**

```
export class Modal {

  protected modal: any = null;

  close() {
    this.modal.close();
  }

}
```

**ModalService**

```
import { ApplicationRef, ComponentFactoryResolver, EmbeddedViewRef, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ModalService {

  private componentRef: any;
  private modalContainer: any;

  constructor(
    private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private appRef: ApplicationRef,
    private injector: Injector) { }

  private createFormModal(component: any): Element {

    this.componentRef = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component.component).create(this.injector);

    this.componentRef.instance.modal = this;

    this.appRef.attachView(this.componentRef.hostView);

    return (this.componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
  }

  open(component: any): void {

    const alertElement = this.createFormModal(component);

    const content = document.createElement('div');
    content.classList.add('modal');
    content.appendChild(alertElement);

    this.modalContainer = document.createElement('div');
    this.modalContainer.classList.add('modal');
    this.modalContainer.appendChild(content);

    document.body.appendChild(this.modalContainer);

  }

  close(): void {
    this.appRef.detachView(this.componentRef.hostView);
    this.modalContainer.parentNode.removeChild(this.modalContainer);
    this.componentRef.destroy();
  }

}
```

I am not sure if this is the best option but it is not working ...

When I try to open the modal I get the following error:

```
Error: No component factory found for HelloComponent. 
       Did you add it to  Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

What am I missing? And can I improve this ModalService code?

Comment: Check my answer , I have fixed the stackblitz demo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the error suggests , you need to add the component in the `entryComponents`array of your root module `app.module.ts` if  you need to render the component as the modal content. This is required because as per the angular documentation if you are dynamically loading a component by type imperatively(using `ComponentFactoryResolver`) then you need to add that component in the `entryComponents`array of your root module. 
Because these components are not referenced in your angular app by template or by selector.

So your `app.module.ts` should look like this -

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HelloComponent } from './hello.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
  entryComponents:[HelloComponent],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is the updated stackblitz demo -

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mk-angular-modal-service-6qhrps

Here is more information on `entryComponents`

https://angular.io/guide/entry-components

There are still some css issue in your modal which needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Add `HelloComponent` in entry component of `@NgModule`:

```
@NgModule({
     imports:[ BrowserModule, FormsModule ],
     declarations:[ AppComponent, HelloComponent ],
      entryComponents:[HelloComponent],
      bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
 })

 export class AppModule { }
```